# Как и где хранить frontend код( javascript, html, css) на сервере?

Tags: php, javascript, сервер, frontend, backend

Всем привет!
Сервер - apache, серверный язык php.
Приложение работает по след. принципу:
1. По запросу клиента php генерирует html, css, js-код.
2. css и js сохраняет во временный каталог на сервере.
3. Клиенту отправляет html со ссылками на .css и .js во временном каталоге.
4. По истечении времени если пользователь не активен - каталог удаляется.


Вопрос - где лучше хранить модули frontend-кода(поправьте терминологию, если не верно):
1. В Базе  данных(postgresql).
2. В каталоге на сервере в виде отдельных файлов-модулей.

Плюсы хранения в БД:
Всё в одном месте, запросы и репликация происходят из одного источника.
Скорость работы -  ещё не тестировал, но, кажется, поиск, выдача результатов будет быстрее, чем в файловой системе

Минусы:
Сложность замены frontend - всё делать через запросы к БД
Увеличение нагрузки на БД

Плюс хранения в файловой системе(они же может быть и минусом):
Легкость редактирования/замены frontend - через тот же vim)))))))

Comment: Вопросы 1) будет ли актвная раздача хтмл и т.д. кода сервером? если да, то лучше хранить в файлах и отдавать напрямую апачем 2) нужно ли проверять права доступа на доступ к файлам? если да - то лучше хранить в БД

Comment: @IvanBolnikh проверить права можно и без хранения в базе.